# Microservice architecture pattern

Tags: microservices

I'm working on a new project where we are using microservices pattern, but i have a one question about some specific processes. For example, we have this structure:

```
   / -> MS1 -> DB1
UI - -> MS2 -> DB2
   \ -> MS3 -> DB3
```

All is clear at this part, but in certain processes we need to make some complex processes involving 2 or more microservices calls.

What is the best approach? Having an intermediate service to handle those "complex" requests? Perform all those calls on FrontEnd part?

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider when you have a process which requires calls to multiple microservices is how strong you need the consistency to be between the services.  The weaker the consistency required, the less of a problem you have.

If the process requires sufficiently strong consistency, the next thing to consider is whether it's practical to combine the services the process interacts with into one service.  If this is practical, then combine the services.

Consistency between services is hard.  You make it easy by eliminating the consistency requirement or by only having one service.

Sometimes you're left with needing consistency between services.  Here, the most effective thing to do is generally going to be to implement the saga pattern: you have an intermediate service manage the process and respond to failures by applying compensating actions (e.g. rollbacks).  You may well need to specially design the APIs of your microservices to support this sort of thing: REST-style APIs are often particularly difficult (consider what rollback looks like when you've only got GET/PUT/DELETE).

Comment: The buzzword you could use for googling is edge-service. Netflix wrote some articles about this concept.

Comment: Saga is what it's been called since before netflix existed (or at least before Netflix used microservices)... :)

Comment: sure, didn't say netflix invented it :). But from my perspective this concept got much more attention in the microservice domain since netflix published about it. 

Thats also why I called it just "Buzzword".

Comment: Thank you for the advice Levi and Simon, i'm going to search more about it to view which approach fits the best for our project. Also, i was looking about the API Gateway approach, but is the same scenario i described in the answer, but avoiding connecting UI directly to the services. Is good to have both of them? (Saga/Edge and API Gateway)

Comment: It's a common approach to have both. Often the API Gateway handles authentication and routing and edge-services the logic to combine service logic. 
Start your search with "layered microservices architecture".